# Simplify use of bundle contains key Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin

I would like to check whether the bundle has the specified key.

Is there any modern way using kotlin to check it?

For now I was using

```
    if(bundle.containsKey(Extras.PRODUCT){
    bundle.getParcelable<Product>(Extras.PRODUCT)?.let{
    mpresenter.mProduct = it
     } 
    }
    
    if(bundle.containsKey(Extras.ANIMAL){
    bundle.getParcelable<ANIMAL>(Extras.ANIMAL)?.let{
    mpresenter.mAnimal = it
      }
    }
```

... an so on

its okay if I only check one value of the Extras. But What if I have 10 or more variable in presenter. Is there any simpler solution for my case?

Comment: Can't you make one big parcelable object that will contain all fields you need instead of assigning keys and remapping everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make some extension functions like

```
fun <T : Parcelable?> Bundle.tryGetParcelable(key: String): T? =
    // getParcelable would return null anyway, but this is a general example
    if (containsKey(key)) getParcelable<T>(key) else null

bundle.tryGetParcelable<Product>(Extras.PRODUCT)?.let { mPresenter.mProduct = it }
```

---

If that's still too wordy, you can pass property references and call `set` on those, like this:

```
// Upper bound isn't nullable now, since we're only assigning if the value is non-null
fun <T : Parcelable> Bundle.tryAssign(key: String, property: KMutableProperty0<T>) {
    tryGetParcelable<T>(key)?.let { property.set(it) } // or let(property::set)
}

bundle.tryAssign<Product>(Extras.PRODUCT, mPresenter::mProduct)
```

but you might want to make the property the receiver instead, so it reads more like the usual `thing = whatever`

```
fun <T : Parcelable> KMutableProperty0<T>.tryAssign(bundle: Bundle, key: String) {
    bundle.tryGetParcelable<T>(key)?.let { set(it) } // or run(::set)
}

mPresenter::mProduct.tryAssign<Product>(bundle, Extras.PRODUCT)
```

---

You'll need to make `tryGetX` functions for each type of Bundle getter you need, `getString` returns nulls but `getInt` always returns an `Int`, so it helps to have handlers that do the `containsKey` check so you don't need to worry about coming up with suitable, reserved default values for "not present".

If you make all those basic getter functions the same way (returning nullables) you can reuse that `tryAssign` function if you like, passing in the appropriate getter:

```
// Not using this here but it's the same getter signature, (Bundle, String) -> T?
// Note that because we're going to be passing references to these functions, we can't 
// define them as extension functions in the same file - so the Bundle is a parameter now
fun tryGetString(bundle: Bundle, key: String): String? {
    return bundle.getString(key)
}

// Now we're passing in the getter function we want to use, which returns a T?
// T doesn't have a Parcelable upper bound anymore
fun <T> KMutableProperty0<T>.tryAssign(bundle: Bundle, key: String, tryGet: (Bundle, String) -> T?) {
    tryGet(bundle, key)?.run(::set)
}

// you won't need the type in diamond brackets, it's just for illustration
mPresenter::mProduct.tryAssign<Product>(bundle, Extras.PRODUCT, ::tryGetParcelable)
```

I mean, this is starting to get a bit intense, but if you have a lot of stuff to assign it might be worth having it cleanly ordered like this? Some stuff to try anyway!

Comment: wow.. so amazing that extension func really helps a lot. @cactustictacs thank you for all the answers  case by case really helps.

Answer (score 0):

[Jetpack Navigation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation) with [Safe Args](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#Safe-args) is now the recommended for navigating and passing data

Related Codelab [Android Navigation](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-navigation#7)

> The navigation component has a Gradle plugin, called safe args, that
> generates simple object and builder classes for type-safe access to
> arguments specified for destinations and actions.
>
> Safe args allows you to get rid of code like this when passing values
> between destinations:
>
> `val username = arguments?.getString("usernameKey")` And, instead,
> replace it with code that has generated setters and getters.
>
> `val username = args.username`

Comment: well to bad that my current company still using the old way, maybe near future gonna use it in full features.  some features already implement navigation and im also using it to pass the bundle / args safeargs. thank you for your reply.